# Jax-rs(Jersey) to Consumes Array of Json object in POST request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Using the jax-rs(Jersey) I am try to implement a POST request that take a list of JSON object

```
//The resource look like this
@Path("/path")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void setJsonl(List<SomeObj> test) {
  //do work
  System.out.println(test);
}


//The class to define the json structure
@XmlRootElement
public class SomeObj{

private String tag;
private String value;

public String getTag() {
 return tag;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
  this.tag = tag;
}

public String getValue() {
  return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
  this.value = value;
}
}
```

how ever when I try to test the REST api using curl I always get a "bad request" error, am I missing something here?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"SomeObj":[{"tag":"abc", "value":"ghi"},{"tag":"123", "value":"456"}]}' http://{host_name}:8080/path_to_resource
```

Comment: So, how did you solve it? According to user311174's answer there is no support for a direct mapping of json. Is that true?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind changing the signature of your method:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

    //The resource look like this
    @Path("/path")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void setJsonl(String array){
        JSONArray o = new JSONArray(last_data);
        System.out.println(o.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

a late answer but may be helpful for others
Post this:

> [{"tag":"abc", "value":"ghi"},{"tag":"123", "value":"456"}]

Because by sending this:

> {"SomeObj":[{"tag":"abc", "value":"ghi"},{"tag":"123", "value":"456"}]}

you are posting an object with a single 'SomeObj' named property. you are not posting an array

Comment: For does who like myself are facing the same problem now-a-days, this answer is the one who worked for me. I'm currently using Jax-RS (Resteasy) with JBoss EAP 6.3 ;D

Comment: But then how do you support application/xml with that? This way I have only being able to post json but not a xml

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your JSON array inside an object like:

```
@XmlRootElement 
public class SomeObjListWrapper {
private List<SomeObj> list;
// getters and setters
}

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"list":[{"tag":"abc", "value":"ghi"},{"tag":"123", "value":"456"}]}' http://{host_name}:8080/path_to_resource
```