# Jersey, how to POST a list of JSON objects?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am building a RESTful web-service in Java using Jersey 1.11, and have problems implementing a method which consumes a list of JSON-ised entities. The single instance method works fine.

The error I get is:

```
Status 400 - Bad Request. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

My method signature looks like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/some-path/{someParam}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createBatch(List<MyEntity> myEnts, @PathParam("someParam") String someParam)
{
   ... 
}
```

The JSON I am sending in the requests is an array of `MyEntity` JSON objects:

```
[{"field1" : value1, "field2" : value2}, {"field1" : value3, "field2" : value4}, ...]
```

Similar questions have been asked before and one straight forward suggestion was to change the consumed media type to text and de-serialize the [JSON manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237102/jax-rsjersey-to-consumes-array-of-json-object-in-post-request) but I'd prefer a cleaner solution.

Is the JSON I am sending even valid in this context or do I need a top-level `{}` i.e a wrapper entity? This would also seem a bit un-natural.

Thank you,

/David

Comment: I post same answer on following link ....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax/43582662#43582662

Answer (score 7):

I think PathParam and also a Param which should unmarshalled by Jersey(JAX-RS) is not possible.
Please try to remove the PathParam Parameter.

And if you need the second Parameter so create a new class like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "example")
public class Example {
  @XmlElement(name = "param")
  private String param;
  @XmlElement(name = "entities")
  private List<MyEntity> entities;
}
```

and also modify your Methode :

```
@POST
@Path("/some-path")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String createBatch(Example example)
{
   ... 
}
```

your JSON Should look like this:

```
{
 "param":"someParam",
 "entities":[
   {"field1" : value1, "field2" : value2}, {"field1" : value3, "field2" : value4}, ...]
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with handling List of objects. I am sending List of objects from client side using axios post and receiving it with Jax RS but I am having 500 internal server error. In your answer you said JSON should be like that but what if JSON is just a list of objects `[{"field1" : value1, "field2" : value2}, {"field1" : value3, "field2" : value4}, ...]`

Comment: I think you need a root node like `entities`, What exception is printed in your log? Because you said that you have an 500 Error.

Comment: I have created a root node like `entities` and my list looks like this `[entities:[ {"field1" : value1, "field2" : value2}, {"field1" : value3, "field2" : value4}, ...]`

Comment: Server-side no exception and when I tried to debug it not even trigger the POST method

Comment: here I have asked this question before reading your post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323401/sending-post-axios-request-with-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so in the end I solved this using a simple wrapper class in order to generate `{ items : [{ <myEnityInstanceJson1> }, { <myEnityInstanceJson2> }, ... ]}`. I guess there is a way to have a generic [wrapper](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/creating-generic-list-wrapper-in-jaxb.html) but for now this will do:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyEntityWrapper implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<MyEntity> items;

    public MyEntityWrapper() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<MyEntity>();
    }

    public MyEntityWrapper(List<MyEntity> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<MyEntity> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<MyEntity> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the generic list type, which is not available at runtime due to type erasure, so Jersey wont know what kind of POJOs to unmarshal.

I think the simplest solution (which I know works, at least when using Jackson in your `MessageBodyReader`) in this case would be to just use a normal Java array instead of the List, so the method signature becomes:

```
public String createBatch(@PathParam("someParam") String someParam, MyEntity[] myEnts)
```

And yes, combining `@PathParam` and a consumed/unmarshalled body parameter should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is valid JSON for an array:

```
{"elements": [
        {"field1" : value1, "field2" : value2}, 
        {"field1" : value3, "field2" : value4},
        ...]
};
```

(see [here](http://www.json.org/js.html) for an example)

You don't need to send text,  you can send it as JSON. Also your `MyEntity` should have `@XmlRootElement` on it (see [here](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.5/json.html), section 5.2 for an example).

You don't need `PathParam` in your arguments, `someParam` is available when the request is posted if you leave the `@Path("/some-path/{someParam}")` in your method signature .

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper class works. 
`MyEntity[] myEnts` doesn't work.

This is what I did and it worked.

```
public String createBatch(@PathParam("someParam") String someParam,
                                                  String content)
```

Use `ObjectMapper` to convert to List of objects.

```
List<MyEntity> entities = om.readValue(content, 
                                       new TypeReference<List<MyEntity>>(){}).
```