# Sending POST axios request with Array of objects

Tags: jax-rs, axios

I am trying to send a POST request with an array of objects using axios. But I am having 500 internal server error and no exceptions on the server. When I send a single object it works fine but not with an array of objects, in this case, it not even trigger my REST service. 
Does someone have any idea?
My array of objects looks like this:-

```
arrayofObjects:[
    {},
    {},
    several objects here   
]
```

POST request:-

```
axios.post(URL,JSON.stringify(this.arrayofObjects), headers)
.then(response=>{
    returnData = (response.data);
 })
.catch(ext=>{
   alert(ext.response.data);  
 })
```

Here is the REST Service(not the complete code):-

```
@POST
@Path("/uvw")
@consumes(MediaType.APPLICATIOM_JSON)
public Response uVW(List<objectData> requested){
   // remaining code
    try{
     return Response.ok().build();
     }catch(){
    return
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail your enviroment. Which kind of application server do you use. What kind of JAX-RS framework, like jersey etc.If you got an 500 internal server error this indicates a problem on the server side so there have to be an exception or error in the server log.

Comment: @Zelldon I am using Payara  Server and when I check the Server log there is no exception, that is what I am surprised to see. I am using Jersey Web Application. And Server just say this :- `[org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter] [tid: _ThreadID= _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener( )] [timeMillis: ] [levelValue:  ] 6 * Server responded with a response on thread http-thread-pool::http-listener()
6 < 500`